# Jquery ui and internet explorer PDF Viewer issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

I am displaying a jquery dialog on page load. On my loading page I also happen to have a pdf embedded like so :

```
 <object width="100%" height="90%">
    <embed src="../../Content/PDF/StockReport.pdf#zoom=80" width="100%" height="100%">
 </object>
```

However in internet explorer 9 the pdf viewer sits above my dialogue and modal. 
I am trying to get z-index to fix this but its not working. 
Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to use [Google's PDF viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer?pli=1), as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)?

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fyourhost.com%2FContent%2FPDF%2FStockReport.pdf%23zoom%3D80&embedded=true" 
  style="width:100%; height:90%;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: This looks really good. My application relies on some authentication, so could get it to work, but a slick solution for standard PDFs.

Comment: The downside is that you have to make public the pdf